WSL2 vscode black extension isn't formatting on save
I'm having some trouble getting the vscode black extension to work in vscode. I'm using python 3.10.12, ubuntu 22.04.3, vscode 1.90.1
Here's my user settings json (edited 6/26 to reflect answer suggestion):
{
    "notebook.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "emmet.useInlineCompletions": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "notebook.formatOnSave.enabled": true,
    "notebook.formatOnCellExecution": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "autoDocstring.customTemplatePath": "/mnt/c/Users/coger/Documents/src/venvs",
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.analysis.autoFormatStrings": true,

    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true
      },
}

Here's my remote settings json (edited 6/26 to reflect answer suggestion):
{
    "notebook.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "emmet.useInlineCompletions": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "notebook.formatOnSave.enabled": true,
    "notebook.formatOnCellExecution": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "autoDocstring.customTemplatePath": "/mnt/c/Users/coger/Documents/src/venvs",
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.analysis.autoFormatStrings": true,

    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true
      },
}

I'm expecting this test.py file located in my ~/src directory to format itself on save, but nothing seems to happen:
'this should be double quotes'

# this should get spaces between characters
x=1+1

I tried to restart the black server, but got this error

 Edit 6/19/24: 
I'm running my vscode window insider a virtual environment and I have black==24.4.2 installed both inside and outside the venv. My black-formatter: import strategy is useBundled.

Please check whether you've installed the black package. You could install it by command pip install black

sure thing (see edit)

You could try to add the following codes to your USER settings.json then try again:
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },


Unfortunately, it looks like this didn't do anything. I tried adding it to both USER and REMOTE settings

Can this answer help? Maybe there's a syntax error which is preventing Black from working.
